# libglui.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ubuntu, libraries

I am trying to run a executable box 2d game machine file. I am getting the following error :

> > while loading shared libraries: libglui.so.2: cannot open shared object          file: No such file or directory.

Can anyone please tell how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS mate 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the game is using the [GLUI library](http://glui.sourceforge.net/). Unfortunately, Ubuntu doesn't include this library in the archives for recent releases. It is, however, [available for Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libglui2c2).

You could try downloading the DEB for your architecture below and installing it with `dpkg`:

- [64-bit DEB](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glui/libglui2c2_2.36-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
- [32-bit DEB](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glui/libglui2c2_2.36-4ubuntu1_i386.deb)

Command:

```
dpkg -i libglui2c2_2.36-4ubuntu1_*.deb
```